# React Calculator - Equal Sign Logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

Hi guys i need some help with the react calculator test project i'm working on for freecodecamp, here’s my code so far: https://codepen.io/mav1283/pen/VGLxJy?editors=0010

```
evalEquation(){
    const {equation, calculations, output,operatorFlag,equalsFlag} = this.state;
    const finalEquation = equation.replace(/\x/g,'*').replace(/\÷/g,'/');
    const answer = String(math.eval(finalEquation));

    if(equalsFlag === false){
      this.setState({
        equation: answer,
        output: answer,
        equalsFlag: true
      });
    } 

    this.playAudio();
  }
```

i figured out how to calculate the input equation every time i hit the equals sign but i’m having a hard time trying to solve or set the logic behind so that every time i enter a number it will replace the initial value but if i enter an operator it will re-use the old calculated value

I haven’t added the % and the positive/negative functionalities yet, i’ll add it as soon as i get the logic behind the equals sign. Also the state display above is temporary so i can see the changes of each actions. Need help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've already done most of the work to get what you want. I haven't looked at your code in detail I just bent it to do what you wanted without really understanding it or checking for side effects, but this should give you a starting point: [Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqpWzY?editors=0010)

Also, cool feature since you're using Babel. You don't need to explicitly bind `this` to all your class functions. You can just use class arrow functions. See the `resetState` function I added.